# MapReduce read file from classpath in Tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, classpath, hadoop-yarn

I have bundled with my fat jar a file "xxx.txt.gz"

I need to reference this file inside each YARN container inside each Map Task.

**So if you look inside my jar:**

you will see
xxx.txt.gz*

I am trying to access this file via

```
File mappingFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xxx.txt.gz").getFile())
```

However, at run time I get the following error from the logs for all task attempts

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/local/hadoop/1/yarn/local/usercache/USER/appcache/application_1431608807540_0071/filecache/10/job.jar/job.jar!/xxx.txt.gz (No such file or directory)
```

in other words, even though my fat jar had the file, the`job.jar` does not.

How can I remedy this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way of accessing the file from Mappers/Reducers. Hope this idea might be ideal in mapreduce.

You can use the [Distributed Cache](http://myhadoopexamples.com/2014/04/16/hadoop-map-side-join-with-distributed-cache-example/) option available in mapreduce. By this way you can make hadoop to distribute your file to all the containers on which your job's Mappers/Reducers would execute.

Comment: sounds like this is designed to do exactly what I want to accomplish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized that in Hadoop 2.7 DistributedCache is deprecated. However, for small utility/lookup files one can add them to HDFS and then use the regular mechanism to load them into the Mapper/Reducer JVMS.

ex:

```
public void setup(Context ctx) {
   // gets the job config, therefore, handles the case where the file is located on the local FS or HDFS)
   Configuration jobConf = context.getConfiguration();
   Path filePath = new Path(jobConf.get("my.mapping.file"));
   FileSystem.get(conf).open(filePath);
}
```